# exams2pdf breaks with url links?

Tags: r-exams

In this RMD file ("q1.rmd"), I make a link using standard markdown syntax.

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
options(scipen=100)
x = sample(1:6,10,TRUE)
```

Question
========

Find the [sample mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Definition_of_the_sample_mean).

`r x`


Solution
========

`r mean(x)`

Meta-information
========
extype: num
exsolution: `r mean(x)`
exname: find mean
````

I then run `exams2pdf("q1.rmd")` and I get the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.3 Find the \href
> {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance%5C%5C...
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile plain1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See plain1.log for more info.

Is there potentially an easy solution to this? I have links in a lot of my questions, and this does not feel like it should break exams2pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kinds of hyperlinks need the LaTeX package `{hyperref}` which is not used in the default `plain.tex` LaTeX template used by `exams2pdf()`. Only the more lightweight `{url}` is included.

So if you want to produce PDF output files you should set up your own LaTeX template which you also need for including header/footer and other styling of the document. You can start out by modifying the default `plain.tex` shipped with the package. Run `exams_skeleton()` or `exams_skeleton(writer = "exams2pdf")` to put copies of this (and other) files in your working directory.

Then eventually you can use `exams2pdf("q1.rmd", template = "my_template.tex")` to produce the output you want, including the hyperlinks.

See also Section 3 in `vignette("exams", package = "exams")` for more details. I should write an updated tutorial based on this old vignette but I hope it's still useful despite its age...